# Extended Regex clarification

Tags: regular-expression

This is an example from the book Linux Command Line

If I am trying to match (555) 123-4567 or 555 123-4567 - the following extended regex can be used.

```
^\(?[0-9][0-9][0-9]\)?  [0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$
```

Simplified to

```
^\(?[0-9]{3}\)?  [0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$
```

In the first example, does the second `?` applies to the whole expression enclosed in the `()`? Meaning it will match either `555` or `(555)`.

In the second example:

```
echo "This works." | grep -E '[[:upper:]][[:upper:][:lower:] ]*\.'
```

Does `*` star apply to entire expression or only to the second part of expression that contains Upper and lower character classes?

If the previous expression was like this:

```
grep -E '[[:upper:][:upper:]][:lower:]*\.'
```

Would the `*` apply only to the lower character class?

Comment: @Theophrastus If the parentheses weren't escaped would ? apply to the whole expression?

Comment: Note that in your second example, `[:lower:]` is just a regular bracket expression (referring to the set of characters `:`,`l`, `o` etc. (GNU grep at least will guess that you *meant* `[[:lower:]]` and warn about that - but not actually treat it as such).

Comment: @steeldriver you are right I need to enclose that in another [ ]. In that case the * would apply only to [[:lower:]] ?

Comment: @Cruise5 yes, AFAIK quantifiers always apply to the immediately preceding regex "atom" only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A summary of the comments by Theophrastus and steeldriver (feel free to edit this answer) with some remarks:

> In the first example, does the second? applies to the whole expression
>   enclosed in the () ? Meaning it will match either 555 or (555).

The second `?` applies to to closing (escaped) `)` and the first `?` to the opening (escaped) `(`. In both cases it matches a literal character. Also you have two space characters instead of one following the `?` in your regexes, so you would have to remove one space to match your example input.

Your regexes would match (with one space character removed):

```
(555) 123-4567
(555 123-4567
555) 123-4567
555 123-4567
```

To match a group you wouldn't escape the parentheses in a extended regular expression.

An example to match `555` and the following space in an optional group:

```
$ echo -e "555 123-4567\n123-4567" | grep -E '^([0-9]{3} )?[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$'
555 123-4567
123-4567
```

> Does * star apply to entire expression or only to the second part of
>   expression that contains Upper and lower character classes?

Yes, it only applies to the bracket expression `[[:upper:][:lower:] ]`.

> ```
> grep -E '[[:upper:][:upper:]][:lower:]*\.'
> ```
>
> Would the * apply only to the lower character class?

Yes, if it wasn't misspelled. You need two brackets for the lower character class and `[[:upper:][:upper:]]` wouldn't make much sense. One `[[:upper:]]` would be sufficient.

So it would be

```
grep -E '[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]*\.'
```